# How do I add a default namespace with no prefix using XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, namespaces, xmlserializer

I am trying to generate an XML document that contains the default namespace without a prefix using `XmlSerializer`, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyRecord ID="9266" xmlns="http://www.website.com/MyRecord">
    <List>
        <SpecificItem>
```

Using the following code ...

```
string xmlizedString = null;
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExportMyRecord));
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlnsEmpty = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlnsEmpty.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, myRecord, xmlnsEmpty);
memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
xmlizedString = this.UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

and class structure ...

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MyRecord")]
public class ExportMyRecord
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

Now, I've tried various options ...

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer
                     (typeof(ExportMyRecord),"http://www.website.com/MyRecord");
```

or ...

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.website.com/MyRecord", ElementName="MyRecord")]
```

gives me ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<q1:MylRecord ID="9266" xmlns:q1="http://www.website.com/MyRecord">
    <q1:List>
        <q1:SpecificItem>
```

I need the XML to have the namespace without the prefix as it's going to a third party provider and they reject all other alternatives.

Answer (score 41):

There you go:

```
ExportMyRecord instance = GetInstanceToSerializeFromSomewhere();
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlnsEmpty = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlnsEmpty.Add(string.Empty, "http://www.website.com/MyRecord");
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(
    instance.GetType(), 
    "http://www.website.com/MyRecord"
);
```

Comment: just wanted to note that you're not using xmlnsEmpty and can be omitted. The overload of serialize that takes XmlSerializerNamespaces doesn't seem to use the string.empty value.

Comment: Brilliant! was also having issues with `<q1:root xmlns:SomeAttr="urn" q1:SomeAttr="urn>` till I saw this fix. just had to add an additional XmlSerializerNamespace for my solution to work

Comment: xmlnsEmpty is used during serialization: `serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, myRecord, xmlnsEmpty);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic implementation that can be used for any type:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(T instance, string defaultNamespace, Stream stream)
{
    var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    namespaces.Add(string.Empty, defaultNamespace);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
    serializer.Serialize(stream, instance, namespaces);
}
```