# How to remove namespace and add new Nampespace in XML in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

I want add a namespace in my xml root. Below is the result I want:

```xml
<ReconciliationRequest xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.co.xxx/test/crm">
    <Patient>
        <NHSNumber>1234567890</NHSNumber>
        <PDSChangeSerialNumber>1234</PDSChangeSerialNumber>
    </Patient>
    <!-- ... -->
</ReconciliationRequest>
```

But I'm getting below result

```xml
<ReconciliationRequest>
    <Patient>
        <NHSNumber>1234567890</NHSNumber>
        <PDSChangeSerialNumber>1234</PDSChangeSerialNumber>
    </Patient>
    <!-- ... -->
</ReconciliationRequest>
```

Below is the code I'm using to add the namespace:

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\ReconcillationRequest.xml");
XmlSerializerNamespaces nameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
nameSpace.Add(string.Empty, "http://schemas.XXXX.co.XX/Test/crm");

serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, nameSpace);
writer.Close();
```

I'm unable to add the namespace. Please guide me on this.

Comment: You need to add above the class :     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReconciliationRequest", Namespace = "http://schemas.xxx.co.xxx/test/crm")]  Root does not have to be just on root class it can be on any class in the serialization.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500111/how-do-i-add-a-default-namespace-with-no-prefix-using-xmlserializer